# Openshift 4.6 creating secret with vsphere-cloud-credentials

Tags: openshift, redhat

I want to create machine set using vsphere provider. In yaml file I see:   `credentialsSecret: name: vsphere-cloud-credentials`. How should this secret look like? Should that be key/value secret with login to vsphere as key and password as value? What if my login is with "@" and I get `Error "Invalid value: "test@test": a valid config key must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.' (e.g. 'key.name', or 'KEY_NAME', or 'key-name', regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z0-9]+')" for field "data[test@test]".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vsphere-cloud-credentials
  namespace: openshift-machine-api
  annotations:
    cloudcredential.openshift.io/credentials-request: openshift-cloud-credential-operator/openshift-machine-api-vsphere
data:
  vsphere-api-url.domain.com.password: xxxxx(base64-encoded)
  vsphere-api-url.domain.com.username: xxxxx(base64-encoded)
type: Opaque
```

i think it should look somehow like this, the secret looks like this if we install a cluster with the vsphere provider and credentials in the install-config.yaml, may i ask why you don't configure this at install with the vsphere provider?

Comment: Hi thank you for response. I didn't configure that at install because I installed cluster using UPI install method.

Comment: we do also UPI on vsphere, but we do not configure baremetal as provider, instead we configure the vsphere provider like its documented for a vsphere install, so our openshift is automatically configured for getting vmdk's from vsphere and such things.

Comment: As far as I know the values above need to be base64-encoded (`username` and `password`)

Comment: @ElytschaSmith We had some troubles with permissons on vsphere because of another part of our company so install this like a bare metal was easier and faster. Next cluster I will install with IPI install type but now with this old cluster I'm trying connect to vsphere and automate configuring new nodes.